# Как нарисовать линию и чтоб вторая начиналась в середине первой?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

В итоге мы должны иметь три координаты которые можно изменять и одну фиксированную в середине первой линии. Мой код может только рисовать линии одна за второй. Подскажите как можно сделать чтоб вторая линия рисовалась из середины первой и потом можно было изменять координаты этих линий?

```js
var line, isDown, mode;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.perPixelTargetFind = true;
canvas.targetFindTolerance = 4;

$("#select").click(function() {
  mode = "select";
  canvas.selection = true;
  canvas.renderAll();
});
$("#draw").click(function() {


  mode = "draw";
});
$("#delete").click(function() {


  deleteObjects();
});

// Adding objects to the canvas...


canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  var points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];

  if (mode == "draw") {
    line = new fabric.Line(points, {
      strokeWidth: 2,
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'red',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',

    });
    canvas.add(line);
  }
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);


  if (mode == "draw") {
    line.set({
      x2: pointer.x,
      y2: pointer.y
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
  line.setCoords();

  isDown = true;
  var pointer2 = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  var points2 = [pointer2.x, pointer2.y];
  if (mode == "draw") {
    line = new fabric.Line(points2, {
      strokeWidth: 2,
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'red',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',

    });
    canvas.add(line);
  }
});

canvas.on('mouse:click', function(o) {
  isDown = false;
  line.setCoords();
});


// select all objects
function deleteObjects() {
  var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject(),
    activeGroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
  if (activeObject) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      canvas.remove(activeObject);
    }
  } else if (activeGroup) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      var objectsInGroup = activeGroup.getObjects();
      canvas.discardActiveGroup();
      objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
        canvas.remove(object);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="select">Selection mode</button>
<button id="draw">Drawing mode</button>
<button id="delete">Delete selected object(s)</button><br />
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Сделал чтобы вторая линия была в центре. Теперь нужно чтобы они были как одно целое и добавить возможность изменять три координаты.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="select">Selection mode</button>
<button id="draw">Drawing mode</button>

<button id="delete">Delete selected object(s)</button><br />
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var line, isDown,mode, x3, y3;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
     canvas.perPixelTargetFind = true;
     canvas.targetFindTolerance = 4;

$("#select").click(function(){
    mode="select";   
    canvas.selection=true;
    canvas.renderAll();
});
$("#draw").click(function(){


    mode="draw";
});
$("#delete").click(function(){


    deleteObjects();
});

// Adding objects to the canvas...


canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
  x3 = pointer.x;
  y3 = pointer.y;

    if(mode=="draw"){
        line = new fabric.Line(points, {
        strokeWidth: 2,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'red',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: true,
        targetFindTolerance: true
        });
        line1 = new fabric.Line([100, 50, 100, 50], {
        strokeWidth: 2,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'red',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: true,
        targetFindTolerance: true
        });
  canvas.add(line)
  canvas.add(line1);}
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);


  if(mode=="draw"){
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  line1.set({ x2: ((pointer.x+x3)/2), y2: ((pointer.y+y3)/2) });
  canvas.renderAll();
   }
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
  line.setCoords();
  line1.setCoords();
});


// select all objects
function deleteObjects(){
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject(),
    activeGroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    if (activeObject) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            canvas.remove(activeObject);
        }
    }
    else if (activeGroup) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            var objectsInGroup = activeGroup.getObjects();
            canvas.discardActiveGroup();
            objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
            canvas.remove(object);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```